# Can Wolkenkit be deployed in a serverless environment

Tags: serverless, wolkenkit

I’m just browsing through the docs+code and I have a quick question: do you see Wolkenkit, or any of its components, working in a serverless environment? either now or in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

Unfortunately no.

#### Long answer

Unfortunately no, if we are talking about *now*. [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) is very strict in separating your domain code from the technical infrastructure code that is required to run your domain code. Right now this technical infrastructure code is focused on making use of Docker containers, as this allows you to work not only in the cloud, but also locally, or in a classic data-center, or … you name it

Of course it would be technically feasible and reasonable, to have another type of runtime in the future, that does not make use of Docker containers, but instead would work with some kind of FaaS solution. As [the native web](https://www.thenativeweb.io/) (the company behind wolkenkit) is a small company, we need to decide what to focus on, and unfortunately, at least right now this is not on the roadmap for the close future. I do not say that this will never be done – it just will take time. Maybe also someone else comes up with such a runtime and enhances the wolkenkit ecosystem.

So, to cut a long story short, if now, then the answer is *no*. If we're talking about the future, the answer is *possible, but without an ETA*.

*PS: I am one of the developers of wolkenkit, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*